# Loop or Function for Tuber

Tags: r, youtube, rstudio, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the exact publishing date for each Youtube video id.

```
install.packages("tuber")

library(tuber)

yt_oauth("", "") # your personal Youtube API access comes here

id<-c("F8wqmh3KybI", "2Llw-utG_mM", "F8wqmh3Kyb")

df<-as.data.frame(id)

stats <- get_video_details(video_id="F8wqmh3KybI")
```

This would be the command to obtain the stats for one video. As I have a couple of hundreds of ids how do I create a function that adds for each id the date of publication?

Thank you very much in advance!

Jannis

PS: In the original list of ids some are not working, so I put in the example one id that does not work. The function should be able to account for that.

Comment: according to `get_video_details` documentation, it outputs the list of `id` with a list of `publishedAt` so the question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can come with something like:

```
install.packages("tuber")

library(tuber)

yt_oauth("", "") # your personal Youtube API access comes here

id<-c("F8wqmh3KybI", "2Llw-utG_mM", "F8wqmh3Kyb")

stats <- sapply(id, function(video_id){
        tryCatch(
            stats <- get_video_details(video_id=video_id)$publishedAt,
            error = function(cond){stats <- "Wrong id"})
        c(video_id, stats)
      })
```